# Delete item from array using filename

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm trying to remove a photo from my redux store using the photo filename however it's not working and I'm not really sure why as I think the code is right.

My code:

```
case actionTypes.PHOTO_DELETE:
            return {
                photos: state.photos.filter(photo =>
                    photo.filename !== action.data
                )
            }
```

And my call

```
store.dispatch(newDataActionCreators.photoDelete(image[0].filename));
```

My actions:

```
export const photoDelete = data => ({
    type: newDataActionTypes.PHOTO_DELETE,
    data,
});
```

Comment: We'd need to see more, the shape of your state and action creators, and how you use the state.

Comment: What does the redux reducer code look like

Comment: PHOTO_DELETE is the reducer?

Comment: is `actionTypes.PHOTO_DELETE` === `newDataActionTypes.PHOTO_DELETE`?

Comment: Yes, it is, just the action which calls the reducer

Comment: We need to see the shape of your state

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this here is the correct way to do this

```
case actionTypes.PHOTO_DELETE:
            return {
                photos: state.photos.filter(photo => {
                    const index = photo.findIndex(object => {
                        return object.name === 'file'
                    })
                    return photo[index].filename !== action.data
                    }
                )
            }
```